# Accessing XAML controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, controls

I'm using this code in .xaml,
as I created a user defined control(`TextBox`) `NumericTextbox`:

```
<local:NumericTextBox Grid.Column="1"
       local:NumericTextBox.Mask="Decimal"
       local:NumericTextBox.MaximumValue="55"
       local:NumericTextBox.MinimumValue="0"
       Name="abc"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Text="{Binding Path=IPAddressProperty}" />
```

I want to access that `NumericTextbox` in .xaml.cs and I have to give that minimum and maximum value also in .xaml.cs file,

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question would be much more readable if you put your XAML up in the original post.

You need to give it a name in XAML:

```
<local:NumericTextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
```

Then you can reference its properties with that name in C# code-behind:

```
this.MyTextBox.MinimumValue = 0;
this.MyTextBox.MaximumValue = 255;
```

Comment: No problem, if it was useful for you feel free to mark as answered.